# How to convert Python DataFrame column with Excel 5 digit date to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

I'm trying to convert an entire column containing a 5 digit date code (EX: 43390, 43599) to a normal date format. This is just to make data analysis easier, it doesn't matter which way it's formatted. In a series, the DATE column looks like this:

```
1         43390
2         43599
3         43605
4         43329
5         43330
          ...  
264832    43533
264833    43325
264834    43410
264835    43461
264836    43365
```

I don't understand previous submissions with this question, and when I tried code such as

```
date_col = df.iloc[:,0]
print((datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(date_col)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

I get this error

```
unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

Thanks, sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: No question is basic, every question is interesting. You should check if what you pass to your `timedelta` function is an integer.

Comment: These are excel dates `date_col = pd.to_datetime(date_col, unit='d', origin='1899-12-30')` or if updating the DataFrame `df.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0], unit='d', origin='1899-12-30')`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the dataframe and assigning it to `date_col`. If you want to get the value of your first row, for example, use `date_col = df.iloc[0]`. This will return the value.
Timedelta takes an integer value, not Series.